# How can I disable the Page Down/Up, when the Focus in on a Button?

Tags: vb.net, truedbgrid

I have a program that can change values in a database. I have a TrueDBGrid in my form and the Page Down/Up works fine. If I click on a button with TAB, this Page Down/Up still works. How can I prevent this when the focus is on the button?

Comment: Will you please clarify your question. WinForm or WPF project?, What is the _Page Down/Up_? Give us something mate to understand your logic.

Comment: WinForms, PageUp and PageDown is on the keyboard. Do the same as arrow up or down.

Comment: I see. Now how about you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58434762/edit) your question to include some code related to the problem so we can understand then we could help. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There is no exception. I just want to know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. That would be:

```
Private Sub frmZeitcodeListe_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Try

        If e.KeyCode = Keys.PageUp Then
            If cmdBearbeiten.Focused = True Or cmdLoeschen.Focused = True Or cmdNeu.Focused = True Or cmdSchliessen.Focused = True Then
                e.Handled = False
            Else
                bsTblZeitcode.MovePrevious()
                e.Handled = True
            End If

        ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.PageDown Then
            If cmdBearbeiten.Focused = True Or cmdLoeschen.Focused = True Or cmdNeu.Focused = True Or cmdSchliessen.Focused = True Then
                e.Handled = False
            Else
                bsTblZeitcode.MoveNext()
                e.Handled = True
            End If
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```